# How well do Eppendorf cups seal?

Tags: lab-techniques

I am considering to send some samples overseas in Eppendorf cups. They are the standard plastic cups of 1 to 2 mL capacity. Of course they may tip over during their journey and I'd like to know how well they seal or if there is any danger that anything leaks from inside the cup. The samples are fixed in alcohol if that is relevant.

Comment: Is this the proper StackExchange site to asks these questions?

Comment: Can you get some tubes with screw lids as these are used for freezing cells? They are tight.

Comment: @Stockfisch Why wouldn't questions about laboratory technique be welcome here? I'm not aware of a StackExchange designated for lab technique questions, though I often feel like one should exist. But that's a discussion for meta.

Answer (score 4):

I have never had  problem with tubes leaking. However, if you are worried about them getting somehow popped open in transit, you might consider wrapping the lid in parafilm. Alternately, there are lid locks that you could use like [these](https://us.vwr.com/store/product/4615516/lidlocks-microcentrifuge-tube-locks-sorenson-bioscience).

@Chris has a good point about screw-cap tubes, they could also work, and are probably a lot sturdier, in case of actual damage.

Comment: The screw cap vials would probably also benefit from parafilm. If you're extra paranoid, put each vial in a 50mL Falcon Tube to catch anything that leaks, then wrap the Falcon Tube in parafilm too.